# Can I register a 3 letter .ly domain?

Tags: domains, domain-registration

When searching for a `.ly` domain under 4 characters long, most registrars respond with:

> All registrars report "Strings shorter than four symbols long are to
>   be registered directly under .ly ONLY through Libya Telecom and
>   Technology co. (LTT) in the upcoming period to guarantee that
>   registrants have Local presence.

Does anyone have any suggestions for getting around this restriction?

Comment: What is incorrect about this question? I am no longer asking for tool recommendations. If this question doesn't belong here, where on earth does it belong? Certainly not on any of the other stack exchange site. This is a relevant question for webmasters.

Comment: I'm reopening it since your edits removed the request for recommendations and made it applicable to other Webmasters.

Comment: Lots of money usually works...

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to get around that restriction.

Typically registries for internet country code top-level domain ([ccTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CcTLD)) like [Libya Telecom & Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libya_Telecom_&_Technology) for the [.ly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ly) ccTLD reserve domains with three or less characters for governmental departments and state run organizations, and allow the remaining to either be preregistered on a first come, first serve basis, or bid on during an auction.

In the case of `.ly`, as specified [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ly#Registration), the second-level domains which are officially open to third-level registrations are:

```
.com.ly: Commercial services
.net.ly: Internet-related services
.gov.ly: Government and ministries
.plc.ly: State-owned companies
.edu.ly: Educational and training institutions
.sch.ly: Schools
.med.ly: Health-related services
.org.ly: Non-profit organizations
.id.ly: Individuals.
```

As also specified there, and on the registry's [site](http://www.nic.ly/), in order to ensure a local presence, they may require trademark registration and other legal documents, and require that domains not contain:

> obscene and indecent names/phrases, including words of a sexual
>   nature; furthermore domain names may not contain words/phrases or
>   abbreviations insulting religion or politics, or be related to
>   gambling and lottery industry or be contrary to Libyan law or Islamic
>   morality.

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion here.

First, someone mentioned 'government departments'. It is highly unlikely that a registrar would limit characters to reserve for govt department use. Second, it is possible. After all, bit.ly is a great example. So regulations obviously don't mean much. Third, someone mentioned money. That is most likely the regulation here.

The regulator is likely reserving 3 character domains as 'premium'. Try contacting the registrar directly to enquire regarding pricing.